# Is having a “type” ethical?

Tags: ethics, reference-request, social-ethics

Some people have a particular “type”, a person with particular *physical* aspects that they look for in a partner.

What ethical frameworks can be used to evaluate this phenomena? Do those frameworks consider this to be “right” or “wrong” (or something different)? Why?

(Note that in some cases, the verdict reached by a framework may depend on particular assumptions, such as whether or not having a “type” is a choice. Please be clear about the assumptions you are making in your answer.)

**QUESTION: Has any author attempted to create an ethical basis for a physical 'type' preference or other means of choosing the company one keeps?**

Comment: Is this an assignment? In any case, please provide your own thoughts on the matter, and where you are having the difficulty.

Comment: Interesting question, I think it has attracted some close votes due to a seemingly opinion only answer set. I added a more explicit question to try an clarify a bit. If I missed your intent please edit or roll back...

Comment: @christo183 That’s a great way of phrasing the question. Thank you!

Comment: @Conifold No, it is not an assignment. I have heard opinions on this subject ranging anywhere from it being racist to have a “type” to it being completely socially acceptable. I’m not sure what my beliefs / thoughts are, which is exactly why I’m curious about what frameworks are available in order to examine and shed light on thoughts I may have about the subject.

Comment: I would venture to say that the choice of partner is often taken to extremes: 1) the full-blown narcissist seeks their own type or someone who is a reflection of themselves; 2) the completely selfless or I should say self-loathing person seeks someone who is as 'exotic', 'foreign', or 'different' from themselves, as possible. A more balanced approach would be taken by someone with a well integrated psyche or personality.

Comment: Confucius was quite into keeping good gentlemanly company, iirc

Comment: @Bread Yes, but those categorizations are sometimes non-physical. (For example a person could *act* differently or similarly.) For this question I'm explicitly asking about physical types - having a "type" based solely on how someone looks. I will clarify that in the question.

Comment: i mean, what's the alternative? everyone is physically attracted to everyone the exact same amount? i mean, maybe there is a moral framework that works in

Comment: @confused One potential alternative is that people have a preference while being open to being in a relationship with others who do not fit that preference because of other qualities the other person may have. That is, the "type" exists, but is not completely fixed.

Comment: well ethics isn't always about absolutes. i mean, personally speaking, i don't think you should worry too much. obviously, if we're talking about 'ethnicity' then that will perhaps be reflecting other social / psychological aspects, beyond 'having a type'. just my two cents

Comment: There are also moral issues with race mixed in with all this - if many people have a particular type that is biased towards or against a certain race, is that "bad"? Should individuals be responsible for mitigating their type preferences in that situation? What sorts of frameworks are available for answering questions like that, and what results do they give?

Comment: @confused I agree that having a "type" is a proxy for more complex processes. But I think it works well enough for the purposes of the discussion, and maybe some frameworks will examine those underlying causes.

Comment: right well if pressed i'd add that it's totally ok to "have a type" but some people can be obnoxious about it... i'm not an ethicist though, so maybe this discussion should be over already

Comment: Take this to its logical extreme.  If it is not OK to have a 'type', then is it OK to be gay?  or straight?   Isn't bodily sex just a physical attribute?  There has to be some degree to which we acknowledge natural aesthetics as an acceptable part of our opinions of people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One useful principle which ethicists appeal to (especially those in deontological traditions) is roughly as follows:

**Ought implies Can:** One ought to do something only if they can in fact do that (even if they might not actually do it).

The idea is that nobody is at fault for not unilaterally solving world hunger since that's simply not something any of us is capable of.  I suspect that the same might apply to 'types', that is, it isn't really practical to force ourselves to find things physically attractive which we don't already find physically attractive.  This depends on the empirical premise that our physical type is not very malleable, which might not be true.  Another possible formulation would be on a version of consent where absolutely no reason is a bad reason not to seek a relationship with someone.

The alternative might be formulated as follows:

**Implicit Racism:** While someone may seemingly have an (innocuous) physical type on the basis of (for this example) race, their 'type' might in fact be just a subconscious (or even conscious but secret) racism, and this racism is the problem rather than the physical preference itself, even though the physical preference wouldn't exist without the racism (e.g. this is pretty overt in most WMAF pornography).

It seems easy enough to make a moral case that this kind of 'type' is morally blameworthy.  The real question is empirical, that being whether this is in fact the source of people's 'types'.

Another way of putting it might be on consequentialist grounds:

**Combatting Systematic Racism:** Someone considered to be in an unattractive racial category may have disproportionate difficulties finding a partner (since our type is likely shared by people in our community), whereas we are able to find love with members of this racial category despite them being 'not our type'.  So the benefits overall are positive to going outside our type and this means we ought to do so.

This relies on the empirical premise that dating someone we consider less attractive is not so bad, and that the conditions faced by individuals who are less conventionally attractive are worse.

To an extent the empirical parts of all of these might be true, in which case we need to establish which 'rules' take priority, whether we need to try to make our type malleable despite the challenge of that due to racial or consequential considerations mattering more than the deontic principle.